# How to remove the final "%" sign from the output in c with printf()

Tags: c, output, printf, stdio

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("hello world");
}
```

The output is the following:

```
hello world%
```

Is there a way to remove the final "%" (which is actually black on white and not white on black like the other characters) of the output?

Comment: What happens if you add a newline? Or use `puts("hello world");`?

Comment: That normally does not appear, maybe it is something terminal or platform specific.

Comment: That `%` is your shell prompt.  If you change your printout to `printf("hello world\n");` (which is a good idea anyway), your output will look much better.

Comment: printf ("hello world") prints without a new line.  The % after  "hello world" is the  command shell prompt . use printf ("hello world\n")  for a new the % to appear in next line.

Comment: Many thanks @SteveSummit, adding "\n" solved the problem

Comment: That might be `zsh` warning you that the command output did not end with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can put printf("\n"); at the end of the int main().

Answer (score -1):

I think that is your shell prompt as @SteveSummit has said in the comment to the Question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer is a bit unclear, as you are not providing a solution but pointing to a comment made by another user. Perhaps you could edit your answer and explain how would you address the question. This way, future visitors with the same problem could benefit from your insight!

Check the following link for further info:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer